# How do I install the Dropbox Client in Lubuntu 15.04?

Tags: lubuntu, dropbox, gdebi

I have a problem with installing Dropbox under Lubuntu 15.04.

When I try to install the downloaded `.deb` file provided via [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) (I have chosen the "Ubuntu" file), I get an error in gdebi:

`Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: python-gtk2 (>=2.12)`

Do I have to install another package version of python-gtk2?

Do I have to downgrade the python-gtk2 package?

I am at a loss and have not found any solutions on Google. I also could not find anybody with the same problem yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nave you tried to look for dropbox in the repositories before? sudo apt-cache search dropbox

Comment: Sorry for being nooby, but do you mean just hack "sudo apt-get install dropbox" into the console and see what happens? Or do I check a specific URL for the package I need?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @Mitch means `sudo apt-get -f install`, without any ` characters

Comment: I meant "try to find out if that package is already in ubuntu repositories", it should be there, called nautilus-dropbox or so. If it's actually there, you can install it with sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox.

Comment: @Mitch, I have tried that, it gives me:  Some packages could ont be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: dropbox: Depends: python-gtk2 (>=2.12) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @ToX 82: I tried installing nautilus-dropbox, it gives me the same outcome I described above. Thanks a lot for helping me btw!

Comment: You probably have a messed up situation, that is why it doesn't install by repository. Try with sudo apt-get -f install, with a bit of luck you will get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed on 15.04, and it installed fine.  It didn't produce any error.

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gpgme

sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
```

Then try to install Dropbox again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it gives me the following response: Package python-gpgme is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.

Comment: What is the outcome of `uname -a`, and `lsb_release -a`. and try what I've added in my answer.

Comment: There you go! Thanks for the input!                                                                      uname -a
Linux Jan-Samsung-Netbook 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:01 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid

Comment: And here's the output from sudo apt-get install python-gtk2:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-gtk2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-gtk2' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue on a fresh install of Lubuntu 16.04. The trick was running `sudo apt-get update` first. Then I was able to `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2; sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox` with no issues.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED:
I solved it by installing the 64 bit version.  I was getting errors trying to install the 32 bit version on a machine I thought was running 32 bit Ubuntu.  So it was looking for the 32 bit versions of the dependencies and not finding them.  It was a little hard at first because I could see they were clearly there.